# CSS classes and ID's on one row

Tags: css

I want to clean the code like this:

Before:

```
.title {
 text-align:right;
 width:100px;
}
```

To

```
.title {
 text-align:right; width:100px;
}
```

Is there a website to clean the code?

Comment: Try a minifier online tool.

Comment: [Check this](http://cssminifier.com/)

Comment: Or use a pre-processor before you put your code online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a **css minifier**.

***Minification: Definition***

*Minification (also minimisation or minimization), in computer programming languages and especially JavaScript, is the process of removing all unnecessary characters from source code without changing its functionality. These unnecessary characters usually include white space characters, new line characters, comments, and sometimes block delimiters, which are used to add readability to the code but are not required for it to execute.* ~[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**[THIS ONLINE MINIFIER](http://cssminifier.com/)** does what you want.

It's description:

*Online CSS Minifier/Compressor.*

*Free! Provides an API. Simple Quick and Fast.*

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Here's a [website](http://blog.smartbear.com/development/five-free-tools-to-clean-up-your-css/) that lists five free tools which can be used to clean up your css, (especially any 'dirty' markup that appears after 'tweaking' your css over time)

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are clean code. The second just has the values on one line. If you want to speed up your css load times, use a minify tool such as http://cssminifier.com/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.lonniebest.com/FormatCSS/

This site is best that i have used. This will provide you much more option that when do u have to use space, new line etc. Just visit it you will get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this site for formatting purposes on my CSS code:

http://www.cssportal.com/format-css/index.php